# Use of -meabi option in gcc powerpc compile

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, powerpc, linux-mint

I have inherited a powerpc project that built fine under a SUSE linux environment back around 2008.  My goal is to build the same thing in Linux Mint (v 17). The target processor is a powerpc, which is set in the environment variables, I believe. During the build on Mint linux, it produces the following error:

```
developer@Will-test-Mint-VM ~/temp/linux.apps $ make -f Makefile.runme
make DESTDIR=`pwd`/tmp install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/developer/temp/linux.apps'
Making install in libStreamerControl
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/developer/temp/linux.apps/libStreamerControl'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../include  -I../include -ffixed-r14 -meabi -fno-builtin -std=gnu99 -Wall -g -O2 -MT streamerControl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/streamerControl.Tpo -c -o streamerControl.lo streamerControl.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../include -I../include -ffixed-r14 -meabi -fno-builtin -std=gnu99 -Wall -g -O2 -MT streamerControl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/streamerControl.Tpo -c streamerControl.c -o streamerControl.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-meabi'
make[2]: *** [streamerControl.lo] Error 1
 ...
```

It is complaining about the `-meabi` option.  I have installed/updated some packages that may be relevant (updated versions of eldk-5.6, automake, libtool, and powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc 4.8.2).

Specifically, I would like to know about the `-meabi` option. I didn't find a lot about it.  What could be causing the compiler to not know what it is?  I saw the output build from the SUSE setup, and it handled the `-meabi` option fine.  Any suggestions?
Thanks,
Will

Comment: Hi -I think I have found part of the puzzle:  the compile is using gcc and not ppc-linux-gcc to compile for powerpc.  I'm assuming -meabi is something specific for the powerpc family.  Anyway, now I'll focus on why the build is ignoring my environment variables:  `ARCH=powerpc`  
  `CROSS_COMPILE=ppc-linux-`

Answer (score 2):

From your comment, it sounds like you're cross compiling here (ie., your build architecture is not the same as your host architecture). In this case, your (build) gcc won't recognise `-meabi`, as it's only valid for the host gcc.

So, you'll need to get your project building with the correct compiler for this to work. The method to do this will depend on the makefiles in your project. You've mentioned `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE`, but these variables are specific to the Linux kernel's build system.

At a guess, your makefiles probably use some fairly standard variables to control the choice of compiler & toolchain, like `CC`, `LD`, etc. Try something like:

```
make -f Makefile.runme CC=powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc LD=powerpc-linux-gnu-ld
```

If your compile still fails, you may need to provide sources (or links to) your Makefiles.